# canonical url for google+ is not working in repeat tag

Tags: javascript, apex-code, google-apps

I have multiple sub pages links in my page i am using canonical link to share my pages but for all sub pages it is showing same link

```
<link rel="canonical" data-href="http://www.website.com/{!object.name}" />

<div class="g-plusone"  data-size="medium" ></div>
<!-- Place this tag after the last +1 button tag. -->

<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
 var po = document.createElement('script'); 
 po.type = 'text/javascript'; 
 po.async = true;
 po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
 var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; 
 s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
})();
</script>
```

I am using this code in apex:repeat tag but for all records the first value url is showing. how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found some code through google documents and its working fine for me.
    instead of using link used

```
 <div class="g-plusone"  data-href="http://www.website/{object.name}" data-size="medium" ></div>
```